# How to turn python method into setter with the help of metaclass?

Tags: python, properties, setter, metaclass

I'm new to metaclasses, so I'm sorry, If my question is somehow stupid. I need to make a metaclass, that takes particular methods of a class and turns them into property methods or setters. So, if I have

```
class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self._x = x

    def get_x(self):
        print("this is property")
        return self._x

    def set_x(self, x: int):
        print("this is setter")
        self._x = x
```

I want it to work like this:

```
class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        print("this is property")
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x: int):
        print("this is setter")
        self._x = x
```

For now I've just realized how to make it for property:

```
class PropertyConvert(type):
    def __new__(cls, future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attr):
        new_attr = {}
        for name, val in future_class_attr.items():
            if not name.startswith('__'):
                if name.startswith('get_'):
                    new_attr[name[4:]] = property(val)
                if name.startswith('set_'):
                    # ???
            else:
                new_attr[name] = val
        return type.__new__(cls, future_class_name, future_class_parents, new_attr)
```

But I can't figure out how to do it for setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [docs about descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), they are really nice written with many similar examples explained.

But answering your question, to make a setter work you need to use the same [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) function but fill second arguments.

> class property(fget=None, fset=None, fdel=None, doc=None)

So code could look like that:

```
class PropertyConvert(type):
    def __new__(cls, future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attr):
        new_attr = {}
        fget, fset, property_name = None, None, None
        for name, val in future_class_attr.items():
            if not name.startswith("__"):
                if name.startswith("get_"):
                    property_name = name[4:]
                    fget = val
                if name.startswith("set_"):
                    property_name = name[4:]
                    fset = val
            else:
                new_attr[name] = val
        if n:
            new_attr[property_name] = property(fget, fset)
        return type.__new__(cls, future_class_name, future_class_parents, new_attr)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Maybe you could also help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358379/inheritance-from-metaclasses-in-python

Comment: Will check it a bit later today