# Inheritance from metaclasses in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

I've got simple metaclass, that turns methods of classes starting with "get_" to properties:

```
class PropertyConvertMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(mcs, future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attr):
        new_attr = {}
        for name, val in future_class_attr.items():
            if not name.startswith('__'):
                if name.startswith('get_'):
                    new_attr[name[4:]] = property(val)
            else:
                new_attr[name] = val
        return type.__new__(mcs, future_class_name, future_class_parents, new_attr)
```

Imagine I have TestClass:

```
class TestClass():
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self._x = x

    def get_x(self):
        print("this is property")
        return self._x
```

I want it to work like this: I create some new class that kinda inherits from them both

```
class NewTestClass(TestClass, PropertyConvertMetaclass):
    pass
```

and I could reuse their both methods like this:

```
obj = NewTestClass(8)
obj.get_x() # 8
obj.x       # 8
```

As I take it, I should create a new class, lets name it PropertyConvert and make NewTestClass inherit from It:

```
class PropertyConvert(metaclass=PropertyConvertMetaclass):
    pass

class NewTestClass(TestClass, PropertyConvert):
    pass
```

But it doesn't help, I still can't use new property method with NewClassTest. How can I make PropertyConvert inherit all the methods from its brother, not doing anything inside NewClassTest, changing only PropertyConverterMetaclass or PropertyConverter? I'm new to metaclasses, so I'm sorry, if this question might seem silly.

Comment: Did you want the metaclass to be a metaclass at some point? Because inheriting from it just makes it a weird object. You need `metaclass=...` at some point to actually use it in place of `type`.

Comment: `new_attr` in your metaclass ends up discarding all the non `get_*` attributes, including dunders. Did you mean to put an `else` in there somewhere? Also, you don't need the redundant `if`s: anything starting with `get_` obviously does not start with `__`.

Comment: Yes, I see that it's weird, but unfortunately It's a task from my programming courses.

Comment: You at least need to call `future_class_attr.update(new_attr)` at the end of the loop...

Comment: Even if you did `class NewTestClass(TestClass, metaclass=PropertyConvertMetaclass):` it wouldn't help. Since `NewTestClass` does not define any methods in its body, there is nothing for the metaclass to operate on. The `TestClass` object is created before the metaclass comes into play

Comment: Thank you, already edited it.

Comment: Your edit does not quite cover it.

Comment: I really don't understand what result you're expecting. You can't post-facto change the metaclass of a class.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a class decorator? Or edit the way the metaclass works?

Comment: What errors do you get form the code in the update right now?

Comment: yes,I am allowed to edit metaclass. right now i get 'NewAndShiny' object has no attribute 'temperature'"

Comment: Sounds like you need to have the metaclass go through the bases of the new class and search for properties there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `TestClass():`, the body of the class is run in a namespace which becomes the class `__dict__`. The metaclass just informs the construction of that namespace via `__new__` and `__init__`. In this case, you have set up the metaclass of `TestClass` to be `type`.

When you inherit from `TestClass`, e. g. with `class NewTestClass(TestClass, PropertyConverter):`, the version of `PropertyConvertMetaclass` you wrote operates on the `__dict__` of `NewTestClass` only. `TestClass` has been created at that point, with no properties, because its metaclass way `type`, and the child class is empty, so you see no properties.

There are a couple of possible solutions here. The simpler one, but out of reach because of your assignment, is to do `class TestClass(metaclass=PropertyConvertMetaclass):`. All children of `TestClass` will have `PropertyConvertMetaclass` and so all getters will be converted to properties.

The alternative is to look carefully at the arguments of `PropertyConvertMetaclass.__new__`. Under normal circumstances, you only operate on the `future_class_attr` attribute. However, you have access to `future_class_bases` as well. If you want to upgrade the immediate siblings of `PropertyConverter`, that's all you need:

```
class PropertyConvertMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(mcs, future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attr):
        # The loop is the same for each base __dict__ as for future_class_attr,
        # so factor it out into a function
        def update(d):
            for name, value in d.items():
                # Don't check for dunders: dunder can't start with `get_`
                if name.startswith('get_') and callable(value):
                    prop = name[4:]
                    # Getter and setter can't be defined in separate classes
                    if 'set_' + prop in d and callable(d['set_' + prop]):
                        setter = d['set_' + prop]
                    else:
                        setter = None
                    if 'del_' + prop in d and callable(d['del_' + prop]):
                        deleter = d['del_' + prop]
                    else:
                        deleter = None
                    future_class_attr[prop] = property(getter, setter, deleter)

        update(future_class_dict)
        for base in future_class_parents:
            # Won't work well with __slots__ or custom __getattr__
            update(base.__dict__)
    return super().__new__(mcs, future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attr)
```

This is probably adequate for your assignment, but lacks a certain amount of finesse. Specifically, there are two deficiencies that I can see:

1. There is no lookup beyond the immediate base classes.
2. You can't define a getter in one class and a setter in another.

To address the first issue, you will have to traverse the MRO of the class. As [@jsbueno suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70365908/2988730), this is easier to do on the fully constructed class using `__init__` rather than the pre-class dictionary. I would solve the second issue by making a table of available getters and setters before making any properties. You could also make the properties respect MRO by doing this. The only complication with using `__init__` is that you have to call `setattr` on the class rather than simply updating its future `__dict__`.

```
class PropertyConvertMetaclass(type):
    def __init__(cls, class_name, class_parents, class_attr):
        getters = set()
        setters = set()
        deleters = set()

        for base in cls.__mro__:
            for name, value in base.__dict__.items():
                if name.startswith('get_') and callable(value):
                    getters.add(name[4:])
                if name.startswith('set_') and callable(value):
                    setters.add(name[4:])
                if name.startswith('del_') and callable(value):
                    deleters.add(name[4:])

        for name in getters:
            def getter(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return getattr(super(cls, self), 'get_' + name)(*args, **kwargs)
            if name in setters:
                def setter(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    return getattr(super(cls, self), 'set_' + name)(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                setter = None
            if name in deleters:
                def deleter(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    return getattr(super(cls, self), 'del_' + name)(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                deleter = None
            setattr(cls, name, property(getter, setter, deleter)
```

Anything that you do in the `__init__` of a metaclass can just as easily be done with a class decorator. The main difference is that the metaclass will apply to all child classes, while a decorator only applies where it is used.

Comment: thank you. it seems though, that must be some way (I edited my question a bit).

Comment: it is not "impossible", you just have to introspect the base classes instead of only looking at the current class namespace.

Comment: @jsbueno. Your right, unusual but not impossible. This is what happens when I answer questions late as night.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing "impossible" there.
It is a problem that, however unusual, can be solved with metaclasses.

Your approach is good - the problem you got is that when you look into the "future_class_attr" (also known as the namespace in the classbody), it only contains the methods and attributes for the class *currently being defined* . In your examples, `NewTestClass` is empty, and so is "future_class_attr".

The way to overcome that is to check instead on all base classes, looking for the methods that match the pattern you are looking for, and then creating the appropriate property.

Doing this correctly *before* creating the target class would be tricky - for one would have to do attribute searching in the correct mro (method resolution order) of all superclasses -and there can be a lot of corner cases. (but note it is not "impossible", nonetheless)

But nothing prevents you of doing that *after* creating the new class. For that, you can just assign the return value of `super().__new__(mcls, ...)`  to a variable (by the way, prefer using `super().__new__` instead of hardcoding `type.__new__`: this allows your metaclass to be colaborative and be combined with, say, collections.ABC or enum.Enum). That variable is them your completed class and you can use `dir` on it to check for all attribute and method names, already consolidating all superclasses - then, just create your new properties and assign then to the newly created class with `setattr(cls_variable, property_name, property_object)`.

Better yet, write the metaclass `__init__` instead of its `__new__` method: you retrieve the new class already created, and can proceed to introspecting it with `dir` and adding the properties immediately. (don't forget to call `super().__init__(...)` even though *your class* don't need it.)

Also, note that since Python 3.6, the same results can be achieved with no metaclass at all, if one just implements the needed logic in the `__init_subclass__` method of a base class.

Comment: It doesn't have to be tricky because MRO is handled correctly by `super`.

Comment: Also, you could apply a decorator and use `dir`, which actually would be trickier

Comment: I updated my answer to show a way to do this pretty generally using `super` without having to worry about MRO. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions of my problem is parsing parents' dicts in PropertyConvertMetaclass:

```
class PropertyConvertMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(mcs, future_class_name, future_class_parents, future_class_attr):
        new_attr = {}
        for parent in future_class_parents:
            for name, val in parent.__dict__.items():
                if not name.startswith('__'):
                    if name.startswith('get_'):
                        new_attr[name[4:]] = property(val, parent.__dict__['set_' + name[4:]])
                new_attr[name] = val

        for name, val in future_class_attr.items():
            if not name.startswith('__'):
                if name.startswith('get_'):
                    new_attr[name[4:]] = property(val, future_class_attr['set_'+name[4:]])
            new_attr[name] = val
        return type.__new__(mcs, future_class_name, future_class_parents, new_attr)
```

Comment: I posted a very similar answer, but with cleaned up code (didn't see yours on mobile). Will update to avoid duplication

Comment: See my updated version. It's much more general: you can define getters, setter and deleters in different classes now, and have a property correctly generated.